# methods in document.ready are executing when redirects to same page after validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have written some code in jsp

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#invDiffAccount").trigger("change");
$("#adatAccount").trigger("change");
$("#originalInvNo").trigger("keyup");



$("#originalInvNo").keyup(function() {
        //////calling json //////
    });

$('#confirmationParty').change(function(){
    ///setting some label values///
    });

$('#invDiffAccount').change(function(){
    ///setting some label values///
    });

$('#adatAccount').change(function(){
          ///setting some label values///
    });



});
```

My problem is when i am getting any validation message and page redirects to same page

it should execute all these functions since i have written it into `document.ready`

Can anybody tell me why it's not happening ..???

Comment: Perhaps there's a JS error you are not seeing.

Comment: no i am using firebug and it's console is not showing any js error

Comment: Well, the `}` before the last `});` that closes `$(document).ready(..)` will cause syntax error.

Comment: no it's my typo mistake...i apologies for the same

Comment: Are you really trying to run the event handlers by triggering the event _before_ you attach the handler?

Comment: @JanDvorak : sorry I am not getting what you mean to say ... can you please explain...??

Comment: actually i want that event to be triggered after getting an validation error from the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trigger an event before you attach its handler, the handler will not be called. If this is what you're trying to do, *first* attach, *then* trigger.

```
$("#originalInvNo").keyup(function() {
    //////calling json //////
});

$("#originalInvNo").trigger("keyup");
```

If you want to trigger a handler if a page is reloaded, you need to do it in a different way. The event handlers won't survive a page reload:

- the `SessionStorage` object persists its contents when the user navigates to a different page on the same domain.
- the browser sends a HTTP `referer` header when navigating to the page, containing the URL of the previous page. Some browsers don't do it, though.
- if all that you're trying to achieve is to find out if you are on a form submission page, there are plenty of ways to do it.

  - Check the existence of a DOM node: `if($("#my-form-error").length){...`
  - Let the server inject a javascript variable into the global scope: `<script> shouldTriggerX = true``. Be careful about polluting the global scope, though.
  - Let the server trigger the event: `<script> $(document).ready(onFormSubmitDone) </script>`. This has the same problem of polluting the global scope.
  - Let the server set an ID or class to some element that is always present (say, `body`): `if($(body).is(".form-error-page"){...`

Answer (score 1):

you should try this little refactoring:

```
$(function() {

$("#originalInvNo").on('keyup',function() {
        //////calling json //////
    });

$('#confirmationParty').on('change',function(){
    ///setting some label values///
    });

$('#invDiffAccount').on('change',function(){
    ///setting some label values///
    });

$('#adatAccount').on('change',function(){
          ///setting some label values///
    });

$("#invDiffAccount").trigger("change");
$("#adatAccount").trigger("change");
$("#originalInvNo").trigger("keyup");

});
```